# Java: Invalid Keystore format Error

Tags: java, keystore

Does anyone know how to solve this java error?

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
```

I get it when I try and access the certificate store from the Java option in control panels. It's stopping me from loading applets that require elevated privileges.

[Error Image](http://img72.imageshack.us/my.php?image=javaerrorxq7.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the error by mangling the trusted.certs file at directory

`C:\Documents and Settings\CDay\Application Data\Sun\Java\Deployment\security`.

Deleting the file fixed the problem.

Comment: What should I do if I don't want to delete this file?

Comment: To delete keystore follow these steps.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6036134/7284578

Answer (score 2):

Do not include special characters in organization name and unit

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a missing certificate or an invalid format.
Did you already generate a certificate with keytool?

Answer (score 0):

for me it meant that my key file I was trying to import was invalid (it was actually a 404 page not a valid key)

Answer (score -1):

For you guys who can't find the 'Documents and Settings' (whatever reason there may be) here is another path where the trusted.certs can be found:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security
```

Hope this helps!