# How to check if keystore is valid?

Tags: android, key, google-play, keystore, android-keystore

I switched to a different computer (all opensuse linux with eclipse) and I am not succeeding in signing my updated app with the same key.

Advised by [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035970/invalid-keystore-problem) on stack I :

- tried to delete trusted.certs (but could not find this file)
- looked for debug.keystore. There was one on my old computer. If I open this in export-> exclipse, he asks me for a password instead/or asks if it was tampered with of the "keystore not valid". Did not succeed in inputting the right password.
- I could not find deault.keystore in ~/.android
- I have a file that I think is my keystore, but I am not sure it is. Could somebody verify this? Here is the file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13564139/dorienhskey

When I try to export with this keystore, I get "Invalid keystore format". I have this file and thisfile.pub in my project directory. Perhaps this is not the keystore, but the key somehow? Would it be possible that I uploaded my app with the debug.keystore? As I can't find any other.

Should I look for some other file?

Comment: You should use the same key for signing the app, I have done this and it is working fine for me even I have shifted from Windows to Ubuntu.

Comment: Of course, my question is how to find and identify this keystore.

Comment: You are publishing the app to the first time or wants to give the update ???

Comment: I want to update an existing app. I think the file in attachment is not a keystore. So I only have debug.keystore. is that possible?

Comment: I know only one thing that if you have signed an application with a keystore you should keep that keystore file and use that one for further updates and if you lost that one then it might be a problem to update the app.

Comment: Yes, I read that too. Whish I knew that a year ago when I uploaded the app for the first time. But check if I used that keystore for that app (before I brute force it). Could I use a key without a keystore?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42936/discussion-between-salman-khan-and-dorien)

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't look like a keystore. That looks like a certificate.

You cannot update your app with the debug keystore. You will need to use the keystore which you had used the first time.

How to find? Keep looking at other places.

Identify: If you open the file in UTF encoding, you should see some text, like your "Name", or "Organization Name", you might have given when you had created that keystore.

You could try open the debug.keystore and see what it looks like. Your keystore would be similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any ideas on where to look? Or what to search for? A search for "debugstore" only gave debug.keystore.

Comment: It could be anywhere :) Try remembering where you might have put it. I generally have mine on multiple places in my dropbox account. Also, the keystore, on the face, just looks like anyother file. Happen to remember what you might have named it?

Comment: btw, if I open debug.keystore, it comes out in weird characters. Are you sure it is not encrypted?

Comment: You could still see some words like Android in there. So, it's not completely encrypted. But, I don't know exactly how it stores all the other information.

Comment: Are you sure I couldn't have used the debug.keystore? Would play have thought it be invalid?

Comment: You could have. Check by signing your app with that, and try uploading it.

Comment: Ok, it was possible. Problem is, if I try my normal passwords, it says keystore was tampered with or wrong password. But ok, if I could have, I will try some more password combinations or a dictionary attack. Thanks!