# Getting Error generating final archive: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format

Tags: java, android

Getting Error generating `final archive: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format`   while running my android application project i tried everything like update my adt and changed my jdk nothing seems to work.

Comment: have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035970/invalid-keystore-problem

Comment: I have seen this but how to change the pass for default keystore.

Comment: Means have you created keystore for your project? or using default debug.keystore file??

Comment: i am using a default.keystore file does it got expired after one year,because suddenly its stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

Regenerate your keystore for your appsign process in your ide. That should help.

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
-alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

for more information pleas visit that [page.](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Comment: The same as for unix, because keytool is provided by java or android sdk. So you have to go into your java jdk or android sdk to see it in windows console. By default it shoudl be on "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\"