# Eclipse Error java.io.IOEception: Invalid Keystore format?

Tags: android

What happend to me today is this, whenever I try to RUN an application no matter how simple it is, I get this error:

```
java.io.IOEception: Invalid Keystore format
```

I have been running applications on my AVD for weeks without any problem, but today everything went bad.

To be honest, I modified the R.java file of one of the applications because it was showing me a stupid error, that when everything went bad.

Comment: Based on error, there could be some problem in your keystore. Have you tried regenerating it?

Comment: You shouldn't modify the R.java file. Have you tried rebuilding the application? Also, at what point in the process of installing and running the application do you get the exception? Can you post the output from the console?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you `debug.keystore` was expired by default debug `keystore` is generated and its validity is 1 year.you can find the `debug.keystore`  in `User\yourusername\.android\debug.keystore` here you have to delete the file `debug.keystore` and build the project then it will automatically create a `debug.keystore` file.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few questions here on SO that are very similar. Try [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126798/java-invalid-keystore-format-error) and if it does not work, there are several other questions that have some solutions.

Just type the following into your SO search box: `[android] invalid keystore format`