# "Error:Invalid keystore format" when I'm trying to build a sample

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, keystore

I downloaded a sample and after I opened it gradle dropped an [Error:Invalid keystore format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9E1c.png)

What should I do?

Comment: for just building there is no need any kind of keystore file.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have explained is not very clear. This occurs after opening of the project.

Comment: Have you tried running some other project? Do you have a keystore?

Answer (score 0):

if you only like to test the App you do not need to generate a Signed APK.
Put your device in and if you are on Android Studio click this little green Play Button: 
http://puu.sh/otZ8A/fb9ee6b82e.png

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed this solution: [Java: Invalid Keystore format Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126798/java-invalid-keystore-format-error) ? 
Have you also checked in build.gradle if there are wrong parameters about (another) keystore? (it should not matter, but you can give it a try)